# COM DLL conflict issue

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am not a COM developer but in our product we are using one COM component, this COM component in initialized and called from one of our C++ DLL.  This C++ DLL have JNI interface which subsequently called by a Java application.  Here issue is, we have installed two versions on our product on the one system and both are using different version of COM DLL. But each one of version is referring to the only one COM dll not their respective version. 
How can we use two different version of COM DLL on one system which could be referring by separate applications? 
 We are using regsvr32 command to register the COM DLL.

Comment: You probably need registration free COM. If the two versions of the DLL register under the same GUID, I see no alternative.

Comment: What is registration free COM? I will google also but good if you make a comment.

Comment: Do both versions register under the same GUID/ / class ID?

Comment: Actually, the product is same but two different versions are installed on the same system.

Comment: So presumably both COM clients get the same COM server version? Are the two versions incompatible? That would be bad form by the COM server developer.

Comment: Sounds like the developer misunderstood what a Globally Unique ID is.

Comment: @MSalters More like misunderstood what a breaking change is.

Comment: See we added few new interfaces in the COM DLL but haven’t changed the GUID. Same GUID is used since long time but newer version of COM DLL is not compatible with the older version of application. Since both are referring to the same COM DLLL, the older version of application crashing.
So, what would be the alternative approaches here?
Should we change the GUID of the latest COM DLL and refer it in C++ DLLL?

Comment: @CrazyC: Incompatible DLL = new GUID, basically. An application which refers to the old GUID should get the old interface. You may still add *new*  interfaces (discoverable via `QueryInterface`)  but the old interfaces should remain compatible.